# How to get document length in real time

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am getting the comment count by querying the documents data length from db. Before getting the document count it will take time to load, its either i refresh the app or i restart the app. I wanted the comment count to update after the comment is added to the db like stream builder.

this is what i have done so far

```
 getCommentCount() async {
    QuerySnapshot snapshot = await commentsRef
        .document(widget.postId)
        .collection('comments')
        .getDocuments();
    if (!mounted) {
      return;
    }
    setState(() {
      commentCount = snapshot.documents.length;
    });
  }
```

Comment: Then just use a stream builder to get realtime updates about the collection?

Comment: How can I convert it to stream builder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a listener to get real-time changes.

```
QuerySnapshot snapshot = await commentRef.document(widget.potId).collection('comments')
.snapshot().listen((val)=>{
if(mounted){ setState((){ commentCount= val.documents.length;})  }  })
```

You may call it in `initState`